# How to convert a list of pairs into nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a variable like:

```
stories = """adress:address
alot:a lot
athiest:atheist
noone:no one
beleive:believe
fivety:fifty
wierd:weird
writen:written"""
```

How would I go about converting it to a nested list of pairs? i.e:

```
new_stories = [['adress', 'address'], ['alot', 'a lot'], ['athiest', 'atheist'], ['noone', 'no one']] # etc.
```

I am currently doing this:

```
s = stories.split("\n")
```

which gives:

```
['adress:address', 'alot:a lot', 'athiest:atheist', 'noone:no one']  # etc.
```

Then I'm not sure what to do or if that's the right step at all.

Comment: Split each item in the list again using `:` as the delimeter and then add them to `new_stories` using `append()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to split each line; I'd use the [`str.splitlines()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to produce the lines (as that covers more corner cases), and then `str.split()` to produce the per-line pair:

```
[s.split(':') for s in stories.splitlines()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> stories = """adress:address
... alot:a lot
... athiest:atheist
... noone:no one
... beleive:believe
... fivety:fifty
... wierd:weird
... writen:written"""
>>> [s.split(':') for s in stories.splitlines()]
[['adress', 'address'], ['alot', 'a lot'], ['athiest', 'atheist'], ['noone', 'no one'], ['beleive', 'believe'], ['fivety', 'fifty'], ['wierd', 'weird'], ['writen', 'written']]
```